# Mercurial push problem

Tags: mercurial, push

I've just got a problem with `hg push` command. What I did - Firstly I created 2 branches **hot-fix-1** and **hot-fix-2**  made some changes in each branche, merged it back to **default** and closed those branches with the command:

```
hg commit --close-branch
```

If I start `hg branches` I have the following output:

```
default      29:e62a2c57b17c
```

`hg branches -c` gives me:

```
default                       29:e62a2c57b17c
hot-fix-2                     27:42f7bf715392 (closed)
hot-fix-1                     26:dd98f50934b0 (closed)
```

Thus `hot-fix-*` branches seems to be closed. However if I try to push the changes I have the next error message:

```
pushing to /Users/user1/projects/mercurial/mytag
searching for changes
abort: push creates new remote branches: hot-fix-1, hot-fix-2!
(use 'hg push --new-branch' to create new remote branches)
```

and it does not matter which command I use `hg push -b .` or `hg push -b default`
So the question is how I can push those changes to repository without creating new branches.

P.S I used to work with git and was hoping that similar branching model can be used in Mercurial. Thanks

Comment: Just to say it explicitly above the fold: Mercurial can do a branching model similar to git's, and it does so using not named branches but bookmarks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, as many others have pointed out, using a named branch for short lived work is not a recommended practice. Named branches are predominantly for long lived features, or for release management.

Given that you are in this situation, there are a few options available. All of them involve modifying history (as you're obviously trying to change something you've done).

One is to just push the branches as is, learn from the experience, and move on. If the rest of the team is fine with this, then it's a case of adding --new-branch to your push command.

If the rest of the team, or you, really want the history to be clean, then you'll need to dig deeper.

If you aren't pushing, then definitely make a clone of your current repo. This way you have a copy of the original work to fall back on.

I see 2 main approaches here. Strip off the merges and rebase your branches onto default. This will get rid of the named branches or graft/transplant your changes. Both will be the same end result, but the implementation is slightly different.

If you merely want to use [graft](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#graft), that is now a built-in function starting with HG 2.0. It replaces the transplant plugin, and is much nicer to work with as it uses your usual merge tool if there are conflicts.

To use it, update to the default branch. Then, use the command:

```
hg graft -D "2085::2093 and not 2091"
```

the string after -D is an hg revision selection query. In your case, you'd likely only need '{start}::{end}' where start is the changeset at the start of the branch, and end is the end changeset of the branch (ignoring the merge).

If you did several merges, you'd have to pick and choose the changesets more precisely.

The other option is to strip the final merges, and use the rebase command that is part of the mq plugin.

You'll have to strip your merge changesets to get rid of them, and then update to the tip of the branch you want to keep. Select the start of the first named branch, and do a rebase. This will change the parentage of the branch (if you're familiar with Git, then this is very much like it's rebase).

Then repeat for the second branch. You should now have one long branch with the name default.

Comment: had the answer you wanted, so it was by definition the right answer, but I'd be remiss in not adding a comment that most Mercurial workflows assume an immutable history and arrange things to avoid needing `strip` or `rebase`.  In this specific case one does that by avoiding **named** branches for short-lived entities.  Had these hotfixes been **anonymous** branches or **bookmarks** you'd have not needed to rewrite history with `strip` or `rebase`.  Building your workflow atop tools that modify history isn't wrong, it's just not usually considered Mercurial best practices.

Comment: @Ry4an Totally agree. I focused strictly on the question, but should have made mention of best practices to avoid this situation in the future (and first place). Thank you for ensuring this was done.

Comment: Thank you for the addition. I will modify the question shortly to incorporate changes in HG. Starting with 2.0, there's a better command than the transplant plugin. The new command is graft, and provides the usual merging help. Transplant does not.

Answer (score 3):

Just do the:

```
hg push --new-branch
```

It will send over those branches, but they'll be closed on the receiving end too, so no one should be bothered.

See my comment on the question for why Named Branches are best saved for long-lived entities like 'stable' and anonymous branches, bookmarks, or clones are more suitable for short lived things like hot-fixes and new features.

Answer (score 2):

Your `hot-fix` changes were made on branches.  Regardless of whether the branch is active or closed, it does exist.

To push the changes to the server (without rewriting history), you must use the `--new-branch` option (e.g. hg push --new-branch`).

Since you merged the branches into default, there will still only be one head (as you have already seen in your local repo).

If you really can't live with pushing the branches to the server, then you must rewrite your local history as suggested in [Mikezx6r's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314129/mercurial-push-problem/5314423#5314423).

In addition to the methods he mentioned, you can also import the changesets into a patch queue and apply them to the tip of your default.